# tabela com array multidimensional em php com comando de repetição foreach

Tags: php, html, array-multidimensional

site com formulário de exibição dos dados dos passageiros .
usuário poderá
marca uma das opções da tabela.
Quando o usuário clicar no botão “Enviar” irá exibir o
nome do cliente selecionado.

• As informações da tabela serão informadas utilizando um array
multidimensional em PHP.
• As opções da tabela deverão ser criadas utilizando o comando de repetição
“foreach”.

não estou sabendo introduzir o php e o array, ainda estou aprendendo sobre o assunto.

Select com PHP

## Passagens aereas Gato Ajato

Selecao
        Nome Passageiro
        Email

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="d" name="selecao" /></td>
    <td>Daniel pinho</td>
    <td>karolmaiaf@gmail.com</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="k" name="selecao" /></td>
    <td>Karol</td>
    <td>karolmaiaf@gmail</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="m" name="selecao" /></td>
    <td>Merlon</td>
    <td>karolmaiaf@gmail.com</td>
</tr>  
</table>
</br></br>
         <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
      </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deixei toda a explicação nos comentários do código:

```
<?php

//primeiro, criamos o array com as informações dos passageiros
$passageiros = array(
    "d" => array(
         "nome" => "Daniel pinho",
         "email" => "karolmaiaf@gmail.com"
    ),
    "k" => array(
         "nome" => "Karol",
         "email" => "karolmaiaf@gmail.com"
    ),
    "m" => array(
         "nome" => "Merlon",
         "email" => "karolmaiaf@gmail.com"
    )
);

//verificamos se existe uma seleção no post
if (isset($_POST['selecao'])) { // se tiver, exibe o nome do selecionado
    $selecao = $_POST['selecao'];
    echo 'nome: ' .$passageiros[$selecao]['nome'];
} else { // caso contrario, exibe os inputs
    echo '<form method="POST">';

    foreach ($passageiros as $passageiro) { // pra cada valor no array passageiros, que será chamado de passageiro, rode o código abaixo:
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="radio" value="' . strtolower(substr(current($passageiro), 0, 1)) . '" name="selecao" /></td>';
        echo '<td>' .$passageiro['nome'] .'</td><br>';
        echo '<td>' .$passageiro['email'] .'</td>';
        echo '</tr><br><br>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="enviar">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```